# PieChart Laravel y Highchart carga en blanco

Tags: laravel-6, highcharts

favor ayuda con este Pie Chart (de highCharts).
No me está cargando en la vista.
Le hago un dd($categories) y me entrega los datos: Categoria, con su cantidad:

```
Illuminate\Support\Collection {#1867 ▼
  #items: array:5 [▼
    "Arroz y Legumbres" => 1
    "Despensa" => 2
    "Detergentes" => 1
    "Huevos y Mantequillas" => 4
    "Limpieza y Aseo" => 2
  ]
}
```

, pero en la vista me carga el chart vacío, como se muestra en la imagen.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el codigo de mi controller:

```
$categories = \Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB::table('products')
    ->selectRaw('categories.name, COUNT(products.category_id) as y')
    ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'products.category_id')
    ->groupByRaw('categories.name')
    ->get()->pluck('y', 'name');
    //dd($categories);
return view('charts.purchases', compact('categories'));
```

Y esta es la seccion de Script, de la vista donde se recibe la data:

```
series: [{
            name: 'Categorías',
            colorByPoint: true,
            data: @json($categories)

        }]
    });
</script>
```

Así aparece en la documentacion, que entiendo se deben pasar un 'name' y un 'y':

```
series: [{
name: 'Brands',
colorByPoint: true,
data: [{
name: 'Chrome',
y: 61.41,
sliced: true,
selected: true
}
```

Agradezco sus comentarios.

Comment: Has probado hacerlo de esta manera: {!! json_encode($categories) !!}

Comment: Hola @Felipe Gracias por tu comentario.
Acabo de probar, pero me queda de igual forma en blanco. 
Creo que es por la forma en que se deben recibir los datos. Por ahi en otro grupo, me recomendaron hacer 2 arrays,, uno para labels y otro para la data.